# Nautilus File Manager error

Tags: nautilus, 19.04

Nautilus file manger not opening.

Getting the following error when I tried to open it using terminal:

> (nautilus:20817): Tracker-ERROR **: 00:05:21.452: Unable to find default domain ontology rule /usr/share/tracker/domain-ontologies/default.rule
>   fish: “nautilus” terminated by signal SIGTRAP (Trace or breakpoint trap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The needed file is located in [*tracker* package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/tracker). This package is installed by default. But, somehow it may have been removed.

So, install it by running:

```
sudo apt install tracker
```

and retry.

Comment: Its working now .... tnks!